# JSON request error

Tags: objective-c, json

I'm experimenting with JSON for the first time in Objective-C.

Here's the code for my Terminal Application:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=harry&country=us"]];
        NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
        NSArray *publicTimeline = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
        NSDictionary *list;
        for(int i=0; i<[publicTimeline count];i++)
        {
            list = [publicTimeline objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Statuses: %@", [list objectForKey:@"trackName"]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
2013-09-11 20:58:55.524 Tweets[7291:303] -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100391d60
2013-09-11 20:58:55.526 Tweets[7291:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100391d60'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91688b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8bf8a3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9171f40a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9167702e ___forwarding___ + 414
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff91676e18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
    5   Tweets                              0x0000000100000d1a main + 378
    6   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff908e67e1 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

What's wrong? I have followed a tutorial perfectly but I am the only one getting the error.

Comment: And once you figure that one out, you'll have problems trying to get anything out of it if it doesn't have a key for @"loans"; Obviously the data you are passing in is `nil` you'll need to fix that first.

Comment: No, the error you're getting is in the NSError object that you didn't bother to check.

Comment: I'm new to iOS development. If it isn't too much to ask could you just suggest a fix for the code.

Comment: Most likely `jsonData` is `nil`. Have you checked to see if this is true or not?

Comment: The key to fixing the code, as hinted by @HotLicks, is to investigate the error object.

Comment: I'm certainly not going to suggest a fix until you check the error object.  It's there for a reason.

Comment: As the commenters above and below suggest:
- check your errors
- don't assume that the result is an NSArray* - it almost certainly isn't and this is most likely the problem.

New or not to iOS development, always do things the right way.

Comment: So do I print the error. Or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code. My results didn't agree with yours. I didn't crash, but I did receive `(null)` from the final `NSLog` call.

Yes, you should be checking the result of `+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error]`. As @HotLicks has pointed out to you quite rightfully, if the result you get is nil, examining the error object can reveal important clues as to what's gone wrong.

But in this case, it's academic because the result (again, in my case) wasn't `nil`. The *real* problem, however, is that you don't appear to have an understanding of your data's schema. `jsonObject` is a dictionary, but it has only two keys, `results` and `resultCount`, and that's the reason you're getting nil from `[jsonObject objectForKey:@"trackName"]`; `trackName` isn't one of the keys.

Those two keys that you do get, however, should tell you plenty. It told me enough to try this:

```
NSArray *results = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [results objectAtIndex:0];
id latestLoans = [dictionary objectForKey:@"trackName"];
```

and got a result:

```
Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows - Part 1
```

In other words, I simply got the first dictionary in the array for `results`, and asked it for the object it had for `trackName`.

Since you were originally asking for an array, I'm guessing that you wanted all the values for that particular key, so if you use this:

```
NSArray *latestLoans = [jsonObject valueForKeyPath:@"results.trackName"];
```

it provides a list of 50 values corresponding to the `trackName` key in the dictionaries under the `results` key.

EDIT:

One other thing you really need to do is to protect yourself against the possibility of `nil` being returned from your call to `-[NSData initWithContentsOfURL:]` by checking for it before calling anything else. This alone won't fix your inability to get a response, but it will keep you from crashing. And if you do receive `nil`, be sure to check the `domain` and `code` properties of the error object you get back to get an idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Minor detail:  A novice, when learning JSON, should *never* "daisy-chain" accesses like `[[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"results"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"trackName"]` (or even the new notation for the same sequence).  Rather, do each step as a separate line, assigning the result to a temp.  This is *much* easier to debug and *much* easier to maintain.

Comment: @trudyscousin - I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag Where are you located? Are you in India, perchance? If so, try substituting 'in' for 'us' for the country code. The parameters of the URL you are passing may not be compatible with your locale. How's your Internet connection? Do you have to wait a long time (around 30 seconds?) before you get your crash? Maybe the server is refusing your connection. And see my edit to my original answer.

Comment: @trudyscousin I've updated the code. Please see it.